# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity' to type 'System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity'

Tags: c#, asp.net, form-authentication

I have get this error during the site log in.How can i resolve this problem.[image]

Answer (score 9):

Apparently the principal object associated with current request was `GenericIdentity` rather than `FormsIdentity`. Casting between these two is not possible.

You should carefully inspect your application's stack with respect to identity management modules and all other possible places in your code where the identity is set for current request. If you are able to identify the culprit that sets the `GenericIdentity` - you are done, you could rewrite/redesign this particular spot.

My guess is that this problem occurs when the user **is not** authenticated. The runtime creates a `GenericIdentity` for current request and sets the `IsAuthenticated` to `false`. I'd rewrite the code to:

```
 if ( HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity )
 {
    // your code follows
 }
 else
 {
    // the user is not yet authenticated and 
    // there is no Forms Identity for current request
 }
```

Comment: I just ran into this problem supporting an old application, and the entire solution was to add the [Authorize] tag to the controller.  The problem occurred because the page was attempting to run code that required the user to be logged in.  So now it redirects to the login page before trying to run the code.

Comment: shouldn't it be && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity  ?  The "user" part is missing

Answer (score 2):

The exception tells you everything you need to know here, `FormsIdentity` cannot be cast to `GenericIdentity` because they are 2 completely different classes.

You don't really provide any sort of information as to *why* you are casting, however, the common base class between both those types is [ClaimsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e.g.

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
```

Comment: In the 18th line, a line below the exception, he accesses the `Ticket` property of the `FormsIdentity`. Casting to `ClaimsIdentity` won't help him them as the code below won't compile. He'd probably have to redesign the whole approach to go up to `ClaimsIdentity`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla like I said in my answer, the OP doesn't give any description as to why they cast in the first place. If it is for the `Ticket` support then clearly there is a bigger problem as `GenericIdentity` doesn't support this. My guess is the OP has implemented their own type of security (non-forms based).

Comment: He hasn't probably. He just extracts roles from the user data section of the forms cookie. A common approach.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem because I had forgotten to use the `[Authorize]` attribute on an entry point to my web app that was using forms authentication. The entry point tried to cast `User.Identity` from a `GenericIdentity` to a `FormsIdentity` and failed.

In my ASP.NET MVC Controller I had the following code;

```
public ActionResult Index(long? eventID)
{
     // error occurred here
     FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity;    
}
```

Changed to this enforced the authentication method set in my web.config;

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

Updated code;

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(long? eventID) { 

   FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity; 

}
```

Comment: Indeed, adding additional explanation here would improve your post.  But to future reviewer, this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the user is not authenticated: either you removed cookies from your browser and again you're accessing the URL directly without login.